# Are the two statements concening number theory correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Statement 1: any integer no less than four can be factorized as a linear combination of two and three.

Statement 2: any integer no less than six can be factorized as a linear combination of three, four and five.

I tried for many numbers, it seems the above two statement are correct. For example,

4=2+2; 5=2+3; 6=3+3+3; ...

6=3+3; 7=3+4; 8=4+4; 9=3+3+3; 10=5+5; ...

Can they be proved?

Comment: Hint: look for their GCD. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties

Comment: By a _linear combination_ of $2$ and $3$ do you perhaps mean something of the form $2a + 3b$ where $a$ and $b$ are _non-negative_ integers?

Comment: In statement 1, read: every integer $\geqslant2$. In statement 2, read: every integer $\geqslant3$.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word *factorize*, since that means breaking down into a product of factors. Instead, an integer can be *written* or *described* as a linear combination, or perhaps *decomposed* into a linear combination.

Comment: For first, can you see that as soon as you find two **consecutive** numbers that are representable, the rest are? For second, can you see that as soon as you find three consecutive numbers that are representable, the rest are?

Comment: They're correct expect that the verb "factor" (American) or "factorise" (British) or "factorize" would normally be used when you're talking about multiplying rather than adding.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: Yes, that's what I mean. Maybe the phrase 'linear combination' is inappropriate here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: In fact, I am not sure about the terminology here. If 'factorize' is for multiplying, then what terminology is for adding? In the question I asked, it should be a adding case, right?

Comment: There's [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), but I guess *decompose* is the proper word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question could be generalized, but there is a trivial solution in the given cases.

1. Any even number can be written as $2n$. For every odd number $x > 1$, there exists an even number $y$ such that $y+3 = x$.
2. Likewise, numbers divisible by $4$ can be written as $4n$. All other numbers over $2$ are $4n + 5$, $4n + 3$ or $4n + 3 + 3$.

Answer (score 3):

**Statement 1:** Either $b$ is even or $b-3$ is even.

**Statement 2:** Either $b$ is divisible by 3, or $b-4$ is or ... now complete the argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Use the [division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem): $n=2q+r.$ What are the values of $r$? If $n≥4,$ then $q≥2,$ and we can re-write $n$ as: $$n=2(q−1)+2+r.$$ What are the values of $2+r$?
2. Again use the division algorithm: $n = 3q + r,$ and with $n ≥ 6,$ we have $$n = 3(q-1) + 3 + r.$$ What are the possible values for $3 + r$?

Answer (score 1):

Read part 1.2 of this book:

http://shoup.net/ntb/ntb-v2.pdf

..on Ideals.  An Ideal is the set of integers that can be expressed as multiples of some constant k.  Let this be $I_k$

Your question is whether $I_2 + I_3 = \mathbb{Z}$

It can be shown that $I_a + I_b = I_{\gcd(a,b)}$

And easily shown that $I_1 = \mathbb{Z} $